# Develop web service with using MFC (without .net framework)

Tags: web-services, visual-c++, mfc

Can I develop a web service in VC++ with MFC and without using of .net framework?

I wrote several classes in VC++ and used CRecordSet, CString, CArray and some of the other MFC classes. I want to use my classes in a new project (web service). Then I cann't change all classes to use standard library.
I think , I should write web service in VC++ , without .Net framework (Unmanaged code). Is it correct? Is a simple Sample of web service in VC++ by Unmanaged code?

Answer (score -1):

No there is no simple way to create a web service with unmanaged code only. The easiest way would be to just write a web service using C#.

Than just use a C++/CLI wrapper to access your MFC code.

This isn't a real problem.

Your MFC code should be capable run inside a standard DLL. There should be no UI core at all in it. And remember that a Web Service has no state!

Comment: Then, there isn't any way(hard or simple) to create a web service with unmanaged code?
I prefer to use my c++ codes in unmanaged code. if it there is.

Comment: Your code is still unmanaged but used inside a C++/CLI wrapper... Handling a web Service native is real hard. I would never advice to do this, when you know how easy it is to write a wrapper around your native code. I am sure that are ways. But they are hard. You will spend to much time with just the "standard" things, instead of solving your main problem.

Comment: [ISAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at50e70y.aspx) supports native web service implementations. Writing them is pretty straight forward as well. In fact, what you appear to be perceiving as the only web service platform **is** an ISAPI extension (aspnet_isapi.dll).